# How to put condition in array item in mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have data in mongo DB. But I am new in  mongo. Can some body help me to get correct record from mongo.

```
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5872edaf9704dc26c0cb770e"),
    "type" : "PUSH_NOTIFICATION",
    "alerts" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5872edab9704dc26c0cb770c"),
            "alertId" : NumberLong(0),
            "userId" : NumberLong(1000100),
            "alertCode" : 3,
            "ticketId" : NumberLong(0),
        }
    ],
    "registrationId" : "010080fab2695a984fc16737b4637b40d4bbcfbfcfb87752851c99fd925e8427",
    "deleted" : false
}
```

Above is a single row of mongo one of the table. I want to get record where ticketId is not equal to 0.  ticketId is inside Alert Object which is the array of alert.
 I want to write query in java.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
BasicDBObject Query = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
Query.put("alerts.ticketId",0);
fields.put("alerts.$", 1);

DBCursor cursor = collection.find(Query, fields);
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any idea how to put the same using criteria query.addCriteria?

Comment: what is collection?

Comment: query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("alerts.ticketId").not().in(0))

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("alerts.ticketId").not().is(0));

//OR

query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("alerts.ticketId").ne(0));

//OR using less than(lt) and greater than(gt) operator

query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("alerts.ticketId").lt(0).gt(0));
```